# What is Emacs' "Hyper?" key?

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes, modifier-key

QMK defines Hyper as Ctrl+Shift+Alt+GUI.

XFCE4 is treating my Left super as Hyper, which also happens to be the key that was configured as Hyper in `xmodmap` when the shortcut was defined.

Emacs doesn't treat QMK's Hyper as equivalent to the Hyper that can be generated in Emacs.

Is there a "hardware definition" for the Hyper that Emacs uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it isn't defined.

https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/issues/288

> Hyper is all on the OS's side - I don't think there's any way to map it natively, but you can stick in KC_MENU or something similar to be redefined in xmodmap or the equivalent for your distro.

> http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf Page ~58. No
> reference to hyper in here.
>
> I've had a look through the file /usr/include/linux/input.h and it's
> include, and it doesn't look like there is any reference to hyper in
> there.
>
> XFree86 keycode:
>
> ```
> // Other codes never generated.  The XFree86 ddx never generates
> // these codes.
> // Thus we can use them as fake keys
> <HYPR> =   128; // <U80>
> ```
>
> So I guess it's a fake key implemented at one of the keyboard layers
> after the fact. I think it's xfree86 (X.org) layer, but I'm not sure.

https://old.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/mfgjr8/different_meanings_for_hyper/

> it's not part of the USB HID, so it's impossible to generate directly.
> Regardless, this can be closed.